# Trouble Installing Frappe on Docker

Tags: docker, erpnext, frappe

As I have stated in the title, I'm having trouble installng Frappe/ERPNext on my Docker. I followed instructions from their official Github repo [here](https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/blob/main/docs/development.md).

After opening frappe_docker folder in VSCode, when trying to execute the bench init command I got an error. Below are the full code:

```
frappe@84badc593d50:/workspace/development$ bench init --skip-redis-config-generation --frappe-branch version-14 frappe-bench
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frappe/.bench/bench/commands/make.py", line 68, in init
    init(
  File "/home/frappe/.bench/bench/utils/render.py", line 105, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frappe/.bench/bench/utils/system.py", line 63, in init
    bench.setup.dirs()
  File "/home/frappe/.bench/bench/utils/render.py", line 126, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frappe/.bench/bench/bench.py", line 337, in dirs
    os.makedirs(self.bench.name, exist_ok=True)
  File "/home/frappe/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'frappe-bench'
```

I have had user added to docker group as per instruction and have followed it step by step but I got the error above. I've tried run `chmod -R frappe:frappe *` at the frappe folder but the error still persist.

My machine is running Pop!_OS 20.04 and Docker Desktop 4.16.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad guys, I found the answer.

All I need to do was run `chown frappe:frappe /workspace/development/` and all is well. I can run `bench init --skip-redis-config-generation --frappe-branch version-14 frappe-bench` without a problem after that.